# Sublime Text3でscalaのコード補完

Tags: scala, sublimetext

Sublime Text3でscalaの開発を行う際に、
eclipseのような使用するライブラリのコード補完（「ctrl + space」での候補の表示）を利用する方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: お使いの環境は Ctrl+Space と仰っているので、Windows でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. Package Control のインストール.

1. Ctrl+` でコンソールを開く.
2. [PackageControl - installation](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3) で、SublimeText3 のタブをクリックし、表示されるスクリプトをコピーする.
3. SublimeText のコンソールにペーストし、実行する.
4. SublimeText を再起動.

## 2. Ensime プラグインのインストール

1. `Ctrl + Shift + P` で PackageControl を呼び出し、`Package Control: Install Package` でインストールするパッケージを表示する. (初回は数秒待たされる)
2. `Ensime` と入力し、プラグインをクリックしてインストールする.

## 3. Ensime サーバのインストール.

1. [DropBox - EnsimeRelease](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ryd981hq08swyqr/V9o9rDvxkS/ENSIME%20Releases)より、Ensime サーバの最新版をダウンロードします.
2. ダウンロードしたファイルを解凍します.
3. SublimeText メニューバーにある `Preferences` -> `Browse packages…` からパッケージディレクトリを開きます.
4. Ensime ディレクトリを作成し、さらにその中に Server ディレクトリを作成します.
5. 解凍したディレクトリの中身を Server ディレクトリの中に入れます.
6. (※補足です)手順 4 および手順 5 はコマンドプロンプトからだと以下のようになります.
   cd {パッケージディレクトリ}
   mkdir Ensime\Server
   cd Ensime\Server
   xcopy /e /q  {解凍したディレクトリ}* .\

## 4. sbt のインストール. (すでに入っていれば飛ばしてください.)

### 1. 自動的にインストールする. (手動だと後々面倒くさいので推奨)

1. [scala sbt msi](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/ja/Installing-sbt-on-Windows.html) で自動的にインストールされますので、終了.

### 2. 手動でインストールする. (非 Cygwin 環境の場合)

1. [sbt-launch.jar](https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.8/) をダウンロード、好きなところに置く.
2. 以下の内容で sbt.bat を作成し、`sbt-lunch.jar` と同じ階層に配置します.

   set SCRIPT_DIR=%~dp0
   java -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar "%SCRIPT_DIR%sbt-launch.jar" %*
3. あとは sbt.bat を環境変数 PATH に記述してコマンドプロンプトを再起動すれば使えるようになります.

### 3. sbt を初回起動する.

1. コマンドプロンプト上に sbt と入力すると、コマンドがたくさん走るので待ちます.
2. これが終わると、`C:\Users\{ユーザ名}\.sbt` に sbt の設定ファイルなどが入っています.

## 5. sbt に Ensime プラグインをインストールする.

1. sbt の設定ディレクトリにある `.sbt\plugins\plugin.sbt` に以下の 1 行を追加してください. もしファイルおよびディレクトリがない場合は作成してください.

   ```
    addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "ensime-sbt-cmd" % "0.1.5")
   ```

※このバージョン番号 0.1.5 は [ensime-sbt - Github](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide#installing-the-ensime-sbt-plugin) から得ることができます.

## 6 .ensime ファイルの作成

1. まず、お手持ちのプロジェクト直下に移動します.
   `cd projects\hello\`
2. ここで、sbt を起動し、.ensime ファイルを作成します.

   ```
   sbt
   > ensime generate
   ```

## 7. SublimeText で Ensime を立ち上げる

1. SublimeText を立ち上げ、右クリックを押した後、`E`、`M`、`S` を順番に押すと Ensime を立ち上げることができます.
2. これでようやく Sublime 側で補完できるようになります.

参考：[Qiita - 最強!?Ensimeを利用したSublime Text3のScala開発環境(playでもliftでも)](http://qiita.com/f81@github/items/d2bd694babc132f44416)

Answer (score 1):

以下の記事を参考にEnsimeと連携するのはいかがでしょうか？

http://qiita.com/f81@github/items/d2bd694babc132f44416

Comment: どうして-1されてあのでしょうか？

Comment: すいません。誤って-1にしてしまったようでした。こちらの情報も大変参考になりました。